# My old Blender is dead

Tags: performance, startup-file

I'm currently on Blender version 2.83, and I don't know why, without any sign of problem, I

Can't start it, it crashes instantly.

[image: crash]

I looked at the different solutions, everything is up to date, i reset the graphics settings, i reinstalled blender.

I deleted the "startup.blend" file Blender manages to launch without crash, but the window keeps moving and when I click for example on shadow in viewport shading, blender crash instantly :

[image: earthquake + crash]

On Blender 2.79b I have no problem, on blender 2.93 blender launches but crashes like with blender 2.83, and on the latest version of blender I have no problem.

https://developer.blender.org/T102486

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: graphics drivers is up to date : Radeon RX 580 series, 22.10.3

Comment: Try this @ArkadeN https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/khzhcc/meta_attention_to_all_amd_gpu_owners/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the radeon version to 22.5.1, Blender no longer crashes. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad you solved the issue. After 2 days, you can *accept your own answer* to mark the question as solved.